# How can I make new data frame only includes players who played both regular season and playoffs at the same season? (Jupyter notebook, python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, data-cleaning

Im recently I am working on making NBA statistics to compare performance between regular season and playoffs of the players.  For now, I scrapped datas of players and divided the data frame into regular season data frame "rs_df" and playoffs data frame "po_df". However, I'm having trouble with making new data frame that only includes players who played both regular season and playoffs in the same season. In other words, want to drop players who did not play both type of game (For example, Luka Doncici failed to get in the 2022-2023 playoffs, so I want to drop his 22-23 regular season stats from my data frame.) Since the players have their own ID in data frame so tried to use it but did not go well. I really need your help! Thank you!

The code I used:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
pd.set_option('display.max_columns',None)

data = pd.read_excel('nba_player_data_Per_game.xlsx')
```

```
rs_df = data[data['Season_type']=='RS']
po_df = data[data['Season_type']=='Playoffs']
```

```
temp_col = ['Year','Season_type', 'PLAYER_ID', 'PLAYER', 'TEAM',
              'GP','MIN','PTS','AST','REB','OREB','DREB','STL','BLK','TOV','EFF',
              'FGM', 'FGA', 'FG_PCT', 'FG3M', 'FG3A', 'FG3_PCT', 'FTM', 'FTA','FT_PCT']
rs_df = rs_df.reindex(columns = temp_col)
po_df = po_df.reindex(columns = temp_col)
data = data.reindex(columns = temp_col)
```

and the data frames I have looks like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrU2X.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlOTm.png)

```
merged_df = pd.merge(rs_df, po_df, on='PLAYER_ID', suffixes=('_RS', '_PO'))
merged_df.dropna(inplace=True)
merged_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

and I got

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fecbI.png)

which repeats useless rows..

Comment: please provide minimal reproducible examples of the input and output, not images

Comment: You will want to merge on both player ID and year, to compare for each season.  So `pd.merge(rs_df, po_df, on=["YEAR", "PLAYER_ID"], how="inner", suffixes=("_RS", "_PO"))`.